# finding how many wcu/rcu I used over a period of time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, cost-management

I try to find data about how much WCU/RCU and storage I've used in a certain period of time to better understand: a) the bill I got, b) how to optimize my usage and provision capacity

where do I find these data?

Answer (score 0):

For WCU and RCU you can use Cloudwatch metrics [1], which allow you to review your consumption for the previous 90 days.

Unfortunately, DynamoDB does not produce data size metrics, but that does not mean its not possible to implement. You can use Amazon EventBridge and schedule it to trigger a Lambda function. This Lambda would simply call `ListTables` and then for each table in the list call `DescribeTable`. From there you can get the estimated table size in bytes, which is updated approx every 6 hours. You can then use Cloudwatch Custom Metrics [2] to plot the metrics received for each table.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/metrics-dimensions.html#ProvisionedWriteCapacityUnits

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html